# Is this matrix NSD?

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-calculus

Follow-up to this question: [Gradient and Hessian of this function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213615/gradient-and-hessian-of-this-function)

Trying to figure out if the objective function from that problem is concave, so I need to check if the Hessian is negative semidefinite.

@john316 derived:

\begin{align*}
 H(x) &= fpp^T - pg^T - gp^T - fM^TM \cr && \text{Hessian} \\
 g(x) &= M^Ty-fp \cr && \text{Gradient}
\end{align*}

Where
\begin{align*}
M &= \alpha A \\
p &= M^Tz \\
\beta^2 &= b^Tb \\
b &= Ax \\
z &= \alpha b \\
1 &= \alpha \beta \\
f &= y^Tz \cr\cr
\end{align*}
And $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ are given.

So, is $H(x)$ negative semi-definite?

In other words, is this true?

$$w^{\top} H(x) w \leq 0 \, \forall \, x \in \mathbb{R}^n, w \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first-order conditions are satisfied at any point where $g=0$

At those points, the Hessian reduces to 
$$\eqalign{
H &= f\,(pp^T-M^TM) \cr
 &= f\,M^T\,(zz^T-I)\,M
}$$
Note that $z$ is a unit vector. To simplify things, let's use a coordinate system where $z$ is the first basis vector.

Let $v = Mw$, then
$$\eqalign{
 w^THw &= f\,v^T(zz^T-I)v \cr
      &= f\,v_1^2 - f\,(v_1^2 + v_2^2 + \ldots + v_n^2) \cr
      &= f\,v_1^2 - f\,(v_1^2 + v_2^2 + \ldots + v_n^2) \cr
      &= -f\,(v_2^2 + ... + v_n^2) \cr
}$$
Whether this is positive or negative depends on the sign of $f$.

Comment: In my case, $A$, $x$ and $y$ are non-negative, so I guess that means $f =y^{\top} z = y^{\top} \alpha b = y^{\top} \alpha A x \geq 0$. So $f$ is always non-negative, meaning $w^{\top} H w$ is always non-positive, so the matrix is NSD. Awesome, thank you!